# RE: check for every X increment in C

Tags: c, function, time, sleep, increment

I have a function that runs every second automatically, 
inside the function i have a counter "i" that increments by 1 so every 1sec. i dont want to run stuff every second but at every x seconds e.g. every 10 seconds.

so i presume the best approach is to detect the increments of i, when it increases by 13?
or a timer/sleep function to be called for the function to wait?

question: how do i detect increments i.e. how do i check if "i" goes up by 13?

```
void func(void){

    static int i = 0; 
    if (every i seconds)
     {
       do something
     }
    i++;
}
```

Thanks for any help i get

Comment: That's reasonable and perfect... Especially if you don't want to add another timed function.

Comment: if (i > 0 && (i % 13) == 0) { ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for modulo operation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
void func(void){
    static int i = 0; 
    int x = 13
    if (i % x == 0)
    {
        do something
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Note that this executes the 'do something' code on the first, fourteenth, twenty-seventh, … time it is called.  If you want it done on the thirteenth, twenty-sixth, thirty-ninth, … time it is called, you need to preincrement `i`: `if (++i % x == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is legit.
Answering your question about running things every 13 seconds:

```
if (i > 0 && (i % 13) == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I have completely understood your question.

You can try this:

```
void func(void){

static int i = 0; 
int interval = 13;
if (i % interval == 0)  /* interval can be your every second */
 {
   do something
 }
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the time() function:

```
#include <time.h>

const time_t intervalTime = (13);
void func(void)
{

     static time_t savedTime = 0; // results in 'do something' on first execution
     time_t currentTime = time(NULL);

     if ( intervalTime <= (currentTime - savedTime) )
     {
         if( 0 == savedTime )
         { // then first time through function

             savedTime = currentTime;
         }

         savedTime += intervalTime; // this avoids time interval drifting
         do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run your loop every second, then a more robust mechanism would be to use the alarm functionality available in libc: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html